# Redirect to root url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I want to redirect one of my url of the application to the root url whenever its entered into the browser,

Say if somebody hits `"localhost:3000/home"` should be redirected to the `"localhost:3000"`.

Basically I want to redirect any of the url (my application url)  which ends with `www.any_url.com/home` to the respective `root_url` of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in the routes.rb.

we redirect the /home route to /. So if someone tries to access localhost:3000/home they will get automatically redirected to main page at localhost:3000.

```
get '/home' => redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this has an accepted answer, but just in case someone else comes along, I thought it worthwhile to add a more general solution to route all invalid URLs to the `root url` and notify the requestor that the requested URL is permanently moved.

**301 redirect permanently moved**

If you include the below as the **final line** in `routes.rb`, all routes that are not recognized will be redirected to the root url. In addition, Rails `redirect` helper is a `[301-redirect][1]` which status will inform the requestor (search engine with a bad, outdated indexed link, for example) that this is a permanent move. This helps keep your apps search engine index clean and correct.

```
  # This is a catchall redirect to home (does not help with (e) type errors)
  # CAUTION: This line will mask routing errors
  get "*path", to: redirect('/')
```